# Creating Java Proxy MITM

Tags: java, proxy, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to create a Java program as a proxy to view packets from an incoming source to debug. To do this, I have created a simple Java server application and have edited my host file on the device. Everything works fine as of now, (even my Relay class file) but I am trying to make it into a full fledged proxy. How could I incorporate elements to send data to the server, and send the response back to the client? Sort of like a Man-In-The-Middle type of thing.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.ini4j.Ini;

public class RelayMultiClient extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;
    Socket relay = null;

    public RelayMultiClient(Socket socket) {
    super("RelayMultiClient");
    this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
        if(Relay.max_clients == Relay.connected_clients) {
            //There are too many clients on the server.
            System.out.println("Connection refused from " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + ": Too many clients connected!");
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        else {
            Ini ini = new Ini(new File("settings.ini"));
            Relay.connected_clients++;
            System.out.println("Connection from client " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " established. Clients Connected: " + Relay.connected_clients);
            while (in.readLine() != null) {
                //Send data to the server
                //Receive data from server and send back to client
            }
            System.out.println("Connection from client " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " lost.");
            Relay.connected_clients--;
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Chris

P.S: I'm not attempting to get HTTP data, I am trying to get data from a game I have created. I don't know if this type of data requires any extra handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I incorporate elements to send data to the server, and send the response back to the client?

Try the following example as basic proxy:

```
public class Proxy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1230); // proxy port
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        Socket relay = new Socket("localhost", 1234); // server address
        new ProxyThread(relay.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream()).start();
        new ProxyThread(socket.getInputStream(), relay.getOutputStream()).start();
    }
}

class ProxyThread extends Thread {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    ProxyThread(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int i;
            while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(i);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It lacks proper exception handling, only demonstrating the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't seem to work. I've set up another java server quickly and tried to connect with the java proxy like that, and the connection is made, but nothing is being sent to that server. I'm assuming that the serverWriter variable is incorrect. I have it exactly as you have it.

Writer serverWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(relay.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader serverIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(relay.getInputStream()));

Comment: You're right, just a typo from my side. Does corrected version work for you?

Comment: I have updated my code with your corrected version already. My other java server (not the proxy) is saying that the connection is made, although nothing is being sent via serverWriter.write(). Thanks :)!

Comment: I've even tried making a direct connection to the server (not proxy) and it works. So it's a problem with the proxy.

Comment: That must be a protocol between server and client, which is not text-based, but binary. Please try updated version, it should be able to deal with both binary and text protocols.

Comment: Update: Really awesome code, but when I connect with a game client, it would send lots of connections through the proxy and back to the client, and it works for 5 minutes, but java stops sending the packets to the server.

Also, how do I read the "bytes" (variable i) into actual packets?

Comment: 1. That means client opens new physical connecyioin to the server, while my simple example handles only first one. Try accept(...) in loop to consume all connections. 2. It depends on protocol client and server are using. Get familiar with a protocol and it will be obvoius how to parse it